# Ruby class_eval method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically create methods

```
class MyClass
  def initialize(dynamic_methods)
    @arr = Array.new(dynamic_methods)
    @arr.each { |m|
      self.class.class_eval do
        def m(*value) 
          puts value
        end
      end
    }
    end
end

tmp = MyClass.new ['method1', 'method2', 'method3']
```

Unfortunately this only creates the method m but I need to create methods based on the value of m, ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are two accepted ways:

1. Use [define_method](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001654):

   ```
   @arr.each do |method|
     self.class.class_eval do
       define_method method do |*arguments|
         puts arguments
       end
     end
   end
   ```
2. Use [class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M001650) with a string argument:

   ```
   @arr.each do |method|
     self.class.class_eval <<-EVAL
       def #{method}(*arguments)
         puts arguments
       end
     EVAL
   end
   ```

The first option converts a closure to a method, the second option evaluates a string (heredoc) and uses regular method binding. The second option has a very slight performance advantage when invoking the methods. The first option is (arguably) a little more readable.

Comment: You might want to note that you need to be more careful about the second method, e.g. avoid code like https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f1d8f2af72e21d41efd02488f1c2dcf829e17783/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#L188-200

Answer (score 4):

```
define_method(m) do |*values|
  puts value
end
```

Comment: Great, that works but how do I specify value as an optional parameter?

Comment: Oh just add a "*" to it like so?
    define_method(m) do |*value|

Comment: Right (I just edited it to that effect). Note though that `*value` doesn't mean "value is an optional argument". It means "value is an array containing all the arguments (of which there might be an arbitrary number).