# Define instance methods in Concern dynamically on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I just want to convert user input params into a Time object, so I trying to define a concern for that.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  include DateAttribute
  attr_date :date_column_1, :date_column_2
end
```

But when I write that concern, I got a problem that how to define a instance methods in module's class_methods block.

```
module DateAttribute
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class_attribute :_attr_date, instance_accessor: false

    self._attr_date = []
  end

  class_methods do
    def attr_date(*attributes)
      self._attr_date = Set.new(attributes.map(&:to_s))

      # how to dynamic define setter methods by loop attributes here
    end

    def date_attributes
      self._attr_date
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`class_eval`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/class_eval) to dynamically create methods.

Here is a simple implementation

```
module DateAttribute
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    class_attribute :_attr_date, instance_accessor: false

    self._attr_date = []
  end

  class_methods do
    def attr_date(*attributes)
      self._attr_date = Set.new(attributes.map(&:to_s))
       attributes.each do |attrib|
        class_eval <<-RUBY
        def #{attrib}(*arguments)
         arguments
        end

        def #{attrib}=(value)
          value
        end
      RUBY
      end
    end

    def date_attributes
      self._attr_date
    end
  end
end
```

[Here](http://hakunin.com/mti#handling-attributes-hash) is a great article to deal with such stuff and you can find dynamic method creation guide from [Dynamic Method Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039031/ruby-class-eval-method/2039095#2039095)

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this. Looks the actully issue I got is `attr_date` must call after `attr_accessor`, or the method defined will be overrided again.